# Gnome Tweaks on Manjaro does not launch

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, python, manjaro, surface

I am running Manjaro Gnome on Surface Pro 3 and lately, I'm no longer able to launch the Gnome Tweaks application. I have looked at other posts with the same problem and for other people, it was due to a missing Python GI dependency, in my case, this is the problem I'm getting:

```
gnome-tweaks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-tweaks", line 14, in <module>
    gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
  File "/home/onur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 130, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available
```

I know that the Namespace Gtk isn't available in the said .py file and I thought about manually including it but I wasn't sure how and I didn't want to accidentally break the software.

Answer (score 0):

DO:

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/gnome-tweaks
```

change:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python3
```

**to:** `#!/usr/bin/python3`